# Incredibly fast JS loop?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, for-loop

Today I've got an idea to check performance of loop which I have called "scoped for". The idea is simply. This loop has two variables, "i" and "l" which are defined "one scope higher" than loop itself.
There's nothing else in those two scopes.

I've created jsPerf and got amazing results.
http://jsperf.com/variable-scoped-loop/6

I decided to create my local test, and results are even better ( 1000x1000 loops average time of 5s for "standard for" and under 0.01s for "scoped for" ).

So now I am wondering why this loop is so damn fast. I`m assuming that it's all about V8, but you never know.

So anyone willing to explain?

TLDR :

Why this loop is so damn fast?

```
var loop = ( function() {
                var i, l;

                return function( length, action ) {
                    for( i = 0, l = length ; i < l ; ++i ) {
                        action();
                    }
                };
            }() );
```

Comment: I guess engine has to create variables i and l at each loop for the first two  cases, while he point to the same i and l at each loop for the two last cases. Don't know if this makes that much difference tho.

Comment: Could the javascript engine notice that you aren't using the results of the loop and optimize the whole loop away?

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Comment: @Philipp The perfs are really bad for the two first cases (var in for & var in fun), maybe the question was more about, why loop using closure are way faster than "standard" ones?

Comment: @Philipp
Basically I wanted to see the performance differences between every approach, even those bad ones.
And thats the point of a question exactly - why "scoped" loop is so damn faster than "standard" one.

I think that it's all about creating new "i" and "l" variables on each loop. And maybe also GC is doing some work too.

Comment: They seem to take pretty much the same time for me in my browser (chrome). Around 75ms for loggin 1000x `"foo"` to the console. Wheras a vanilla for loop, doing the same takes about 65ms to to the very same.

Comment: The loop is not fast, it's the fact that the same function is called inside the loop that matters. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no magic here: your test is faulty.

For `varInFor`, the `empty` function is correctly called `9999^2` times, whereas with `varInScope`, it's only called `9999` times. That's why it finishes a lot quicker. You can test this easily by making the `empty` function print something.

The reason why is the fact that variables `i` and `l` are shared between the outer and inner call of `varInScope`. So after the inner loop finishes, `i` is already equal `l` and the outer loop immediately exits.

See [another JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/variable-scoped-loop/11) for a fixed version that initializes the functions every time (to create a new set of variables in the closure) and it is, indeed, up to 20% **slower** than the "normal" for loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! To be honest, I`m ashamed that I've missed such a thing... Anyway the "mystery" has been revealed :)